# Chrome Debugger Broken; Continues on its own after stopping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I've been using Chrome DevTools to debug JavaScript for years but it suddenly seems broken. When setting a breakpoint anywhere in my code, execution stops at the expected line but only for a second. Execution then resumes on its own, making debugging impossible. Nothing has changed in the code, although it's possible that Chrome has updated itself in the background since the last time I've used the debugger.

I did find this post from someone who was having a similar problem:

[Chrome webtools debugger resumes script execution on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316505/chrome-webtools-debugger-resumes-script-execution-on-its-own)

His situation seems different though insofar as he was using an Andoid app and in his case, WebView.loadUrl() triggered the bug. In my case, I'm not doing anything fancy. No add ons or custom APIs.

I do have timers running (as did this other poster) but this has never been a problem historically. When a breakpoint was hit, everything would just stop properly at the specified line. This behavior of stopping and then starting again after one second I've never encountered before. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The bug does NOT manifest in Firefox.

SOLUTION: Through hours of trial and error, it became clear that the solution is to go to the Dev Tools>>Application>>Service Workers, and check the box that says "Update on Reload." This seems to be the only viable workaround for this issue which was apparently introduced in the most recent Chrome update. Hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same.

Comment: This one it is strange one? Could you post you code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Even a script like 'var abc={};' written in the <head> before any other code is encountered will trigger the bug. Setting a breakpoint there will cause a stop at the appropriate point, debugger loads, pauses for a second then immediate resumes on its own. Any *subsequent* breakpoints that are hit work fine, oddly enough.

Comment: Killing a long-running service worker via chrome://serviceworker-internals/ stopped the bug. But as soon as that service worker activates again, the debugging problem comes back.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy over the past few days. Thank you for the solution. Was resorting to console.log() to debug things.

Comment: Ran into the same issue in Chrome 58.0.3029.110 and 59.0.3071.104 (latest) on any page with a service worker (my service workers were self updating, which is probably what triggered the debugger to resume), but your solution works. Might be more helpful to others if you add it as an answer and mark it as the solution.